# Python script for executing repetitive script input

Tags: python, shell, input, terminal

I have a script that needs to execute multiple (9) times with the same input, looking for a solution to simplify the process.

The standard command for my script and operation is:

```
steghide extract -sf file.jpg
```

P/s: I'm running on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

1. A program (python script)
2. N (9) files to process with the program
3. 1 argument (input) for the program

Now, you want to run the script from command line for N (9) files with the same argument, right?

My suggestion will be writing another script to run the script for that N files with same input argument.

A basic introduction for system command line argument:

```
# Module sys has to be imported:
import sys                

# Iteration over all arguments:
for eachArg in sys.argv:   
    print(eachArg)
```

Example call to this script :

```
python argumente.py python course for beginners
```

The output:

```
argumente.py
python
course
for
beginners
```

Now we can modify this simple example to your case.  First, create a new python program and import your python script, let's say your python program name is `my_prog1.py`:

```
import my_prog1
import os
import sys

var = sys.argv[1]

os.system('python my_prog1 file1_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file2_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file3_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file4_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file5_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file6_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file7_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file8_location' var)
os.system('python my_prog1 file9_location' var)
```

where your call to this script is (let's name this script as sample.py):

```
python sample.py "your input here"
```

Now it will get the same input and run for N files.

**[Updated Answer after Discussion]**

Since the questioner is using steghide with command and he is required to enter the passphrase every time.  From the [steghide doc](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/steghide/steghide.1), you can add a passphrase argument to the command.

```
import os
import sys

var = sys.argv[1]

os.system('steghide extract -sf file1.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file2.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file3.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file4.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file5.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file6.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file7.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file8.jpg -p %s' %var)
os.system('steghide extract -sf file9.jpg -p %s' %var)
```

Run this in command:

```
python sample.py "your passphrase here"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't actually have access to the first program. I give it the file, then it takes it in and asks me a passphrase. To be honest, I'm not even sure if the program is written in python.

Comment: @Ironstone how do you run the program?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not experienced with Linux (using a VM for a competition). At the moment I run a keyword in the terminal followed by parameters. To be completely honest, I'm not even sure it's written in python, but the way it asks for input() makes me feel this way because it won't print anything until someone enters something.

Comment: @Ironstone you run the application with terminal? Any example of the command you insert and example output?

Comment: It's steghide, so I run 'steghide extract -sf file.jpg',then I get prompted with 'Enter passphrase:'

Comment: @Ironstone I have updated the answer accordingly, have a try, if it solves your question, don't forget to mark as answer :)